# Git: Why does git say "your branch is up to date with origin/main" when there are updates I haven't pulled yet?

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, git-branch

I'm on a local branch, and switched back to `main`. It said `Your branch is up to date with origin/main`, but when I do `git pull` it does pull a bunch of new updates. Does this not mean that my branch was *not* up to date with `origin/main`?

Comment: If you avoid `git pull` you'll get a better mental model of what's going on. Run `git fetch` once, *then* run `git status` and `git log` as desired, *then* consider merging or rebasing.

Comment: One key to this, which may help it "click" in your head, is that you *were* up to date with `origin/main`, because `origin/main` is a name in *your Git repository*. Running `git fetch` makes your Git reach out to some other Git repository and get updates from them, thus updating your `origin/main`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your local Git does not know about the state of the remote server *unless* you fetch first. Once you have fetched you can inspect the status of your branch and it will tell you, that you are behind or that the branches have diverged.

Almost all commands in Git operate locally and only a few of them need internet access, such as push, fetch, ls-remote